# С какой пунктуацией пойдёт выражение - "а я как все"

Tags: пунктуация

Школьное выражение:

```
-Иванов, ты почему уроки прогулял?
-А я как все //Это проблемное место
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, филологи, с какой пунктуацией пойдёт выражение "А я как все." С дефисом, запятой или ещё с какими-нибудь знаками препинания?

Comment: ответ на этот вопрос можно найти в открытых источниках, в частности на [Грамота.ру - **Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183), потому как он касается стандартного правила

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка ну сделайте выписку краткую, с пояснениями. Очень надо.

Comment: не совсем понятна необходимость выписки, когда информация уже изложена на странице по ссылке, поясните, если не затруднит

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка ctrl+f это поиск по странице. Всю читать я не буду, время ограничено. Так по поиску на странице я не нашёл, то, что искал.

Comment: поиском достаточно найти приведённое название раздела статьи, остальное бросается в глаза само, пп. 1, 3 и 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае как не нуждается в пунктуационном обособлении. В приведённом в комментариях [источнике](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183) перечислены пять случаев, когда такое случается. На самом деле эти категории не являются взаимоисключающими, поэтому можно сказать что "как" в данном случае не обособляется, потому что:

- стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым
- "как" входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без оборота не имеет смысла
- оборот входит в состав фразеологизма

Comment: А дефиса нет? А я - как все.

Comment: дефиса там в любом случае не могло бы быть, тире штука очень часто интонационная, например если бы нужно было передать небольшую паузу (или смысловое противопоставление, как в фразе "Вы - индивидуалисты, а я - как все"), то можно представить тире, но в данном случае - нет.